# Standalone latex table from amended xtable function

Tags: r, xtable

I'm trying to create an automated R function which creates a latex file that can be run (without any further amendments to the Latex code) by an external Latex program. I'm aware of KnitR and Sweave but I need something much simpler. Basically for any object that can be printed out through xtable I want to add

%A1 At the top

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
```

%A2 at the end

```
\end{document}
```

This means that I can just run my analysis and (when I need to) create an external file that can be manipulated by Latex-based programs. I'm not interested in putting all the tables into one document but I want them separate (hence the need for \begin{document} and \end{document}. I've been experimenting with add.to.rows (xtable function) but I'm getting nowhere.

Example:

```
data(tli)
tli.table <- xtable(tli[1:10,])
digits(tli.table)[c(2,6)] <- 0
print(tli.table,floating=FALSE)
```

How would you add both A1 and A2 so that the result is:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrlllr}
  \hline
 & grade & sex & disadvg & ethnicty & tlimth \\ 
  \hline
1 &   6 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  43 \\ 
  2 &   7 & M & NO & BLACK &  88 \\ 
  3 &   5 & F & YES & HISPANIC &  34 \\ 
  4 &   3 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  65 \\ 
  5 &   8 & M & YES & WHITE &  75 \\ 
  6 &   5 & M & NO & BLACK &  74 \\ 
  7 &   8 & F & YES & HISPANIC &  72 \\ 
  8 &   4 & M & YES & BLACK &  79 \\ 
  9 &   6 & M & NO & WHITE &  88 \\ 
  10 &   7 & M & YES & HISPANIC &  87 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I got stuck right at the start:

```
bottom <- list();bottom$pos<- list()
bottom$pos[[1]] <- c(nrow(x))
bottom$command  <-c("\\end{document} \n")
print(xtable(tli[1:10,]),add.to.row=bottom)
```

I need \end{document} to be right at the end but if I change

`bottom$pos`

to

`bottom$pos[[1]] <- c(nrow(x)+3)`

I get an error. I also haven't included the top part (A1- see above).

Ideally I'd like the code to be as generic as possible so that it can be applied to any xtable output (e.g. anovas, sideway tables etc...).

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just use `\input` and a dummy file with the preamble material?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cat` and `print.xtable`  functions both have an 'append' argument:

```
wrapLatex <- function(dat,fil, ...) {
     cat(c("\\documentclass{article}\n",
           "\\pagestyle{empty}\n",
           "\\begin{document}\n"), file=fil)
   print(dat, file=fil, append=TRUE, ...)
      cat("\\end{document}\n", file=fil, append=TRUE) }
wrapLatex(tli.table, fil="~/test")
```

Comment: I cannot believe I forgot this posting. I also apparently forgot to add it to my .Rprofile file as well. I've wanted this many times in the last 3 years.